# How can i make the page wait before it forward to another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am currently redirecting to a main page on success , based on success i want to make the page wait for 30 or 50 sec before the redirect happens and  I want to check while waiting if a 500 Internal Error message has occurred .

```
    $(function() {  
                 $("#save").click(function() {  

                    $.ajax({  
                        type: "POST",  
                          url: "cng.json",  
                          data: json_data,  
                          contentType : 'application/json',
                           success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {                          
                                console.log(arguments);
                                console.log(xhr.status);
                                alert("Your changes are being submitted: "+ textStatus +" : "+ xhr.status);
//modal window message
    $('<div id="loading">Loading...</div>').insertBefore('#myform');
                        // add code here to wait for 30 sec before redirecting and check for 500 error code     
                                 location.reload(true);

                           },

                            error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                          alert( jqXHR.responseText+" - " +errorThrown + " : " +jqXHR.status);                       

                           }
                        }); 

                  });  
                });
```

Comment: Does your code indentation style follow any logical rules, or is it just random? `:P`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a [timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)?

```
setTimeout(function() {
    location.reload(true);
}, 30000);
```

Btw, 30sec is very long.

Answer (score 0):

I would define a flag as the ajax call is fired, then put in a setTimeout in your success.

```
setTimeout(check_redirect, 30000);
```

If error fires then set the flag to false

When the timer runs out your callback will be fired, check the flag and continue as appropriate:

```
function check_redirect()
{
   if(flag===true)
   {
      location.reload(true);
   }
}
```